# 16.04 Desktop - large default packages that can be removed to free up space?

Tags: 16.04, disk-usage

I am aware of packages like LibreOffice that occupy several hundreds of MB, are there any more packages like that?

Comment: @DKBose I could use the answer for that question, but not asking for the same thing

Comment: @DKBose the focus is different. I want to know what packages are "forced"by Ubuntu Desktop that are known to be non-critical, so this is not just about how much space.